# specifying custom properties to a displaytag table decorator

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have a decorator specified on a displaytag table that I need to pass parameters to. The decorator adds an id attribute to the row. Currently the values I require are hardcoded.

The parameters I need are:

- The name of the property to use as id value
- An id prefix (usually the property used is a number and IE doesn't like ids starting with numbers)

Looking through the javadocs for displaytag, it looks like I can set a property (`<displaytag:setProperty>`), but there doesn't seem to be a way for me to return a general property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators have access to the `PageContext`. You can pass parameters as its attributes (for example, using `<c:set .../>`).

Comment: Nice. Used it to use the same wrapper for different language in the same JSP.

    <c:set var="lang" value="en"/>
    <displaytag decorator="MarketingFileTypeWrapper" ...>

    <c:set var="lang" value="fr"/>
    <displaytag decorator="MarketingFileTypeWrapper" ...>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide a little bit more of info? Show us your decorator implementation pls.

If I got you right: You need the id of the iterated property? If you implement the

```
DisplaytagColumnDecorator
```

Interface, you can access the iterated property by

```
decorate(java.lang.Object columnValue, javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext pageContext, MediaTypeEnum media)
```

where columValue is your property object for each row.

Comment: no, I want to add the id attribute to each tr that is generated by displaytag. The TableDecorator interface has a getRowId() method which does what I want, but I don't know how to pass parameters from the jsp to the decorator